# Mobile Firefox is not supported?

Tags: support, mobile-web, browsers

Just found a new article in the help center: [What browsers do we support?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/browser-support)

And it contains link to [Browserlist](https://browserl.ist/?q=last%202%20versions%2C%20not%20ie%20%3C%2011%2C%20not%20dead%2C%20not%20op_mini%20all%2C%20not%20baidu%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20and_ff%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20and_qq%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20kaios%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20op_mob%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20ie_mob%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20and_uc%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20Samsung%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20Android%20%3E%200). I don't see mobile Firefox here.

Was it by mistake or this browser is not supported?

Comment: It doesn't have Firefox 70 (desktop) on that list either (which is the latest stable version). Seems like the list is broken...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox for Mobile is not officially supported and never has been on our network. It has always been in a state of "it works but may break" in [our list of supported browsers on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) (which in fact still mentions version 10.0.3 from back in 2012).

Comment: Maybe we should add link to that meta post to this article?

Comment: @Suvitruf The idea of creating the help center article was so we *didn't have to* link to the Meta question. Sales reps and other people find it a bit unprofessional to link to a Meta question when trying to discuss the product, so you'll likely see more info transitioning into the help center over time.

Comment: But right now there are a lot of articles in the help center already, which contains links to a blog or meta posts.

Comment: Those are mostly the community-focused articles. And keep in mind that Teams has [its own help center](https://stackoverflow.help) that we are currently tweaking to remove a lot of those references.