# When was "What browsers do we support" added in help center?

Tags: support, help-center

This is just out of curiousity and can be considered trivial. I visit help center regularly to link some articles to new users. This is the first time I saw [What browsers do we support](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/browser-support) under our model. This faq [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/357396)

[image: Screenshot from help center with "What browsers do we support" underlined with black ink]

When was the recent edit done to the help center page?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336824/260198 (:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Around October 24, going by [the Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/*/https://stackoverflow.com/help/browser-support):

[image]

Comment: Did all the sites get the change once or SO first and later extended to all other sites?

Comment: Not sure, since the Wayback Machine doesn't seem to have tracked this page for the other sites.

Comment: @NogShine Help center articles are global by default. Changing it in one place changes it everywhere.