# Consider generalizing the "what browsers do we support?" page

Tags: feature-request, help-center

A [new page](/help/browser-support) was [recently added to the help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336895/332043). From my testing on a few sites in the network, all of them state:

> **Stack Overflow** supports the last two stable versions of major browsers

(emphasis mine)

Could this be generalized to "Stack Exchange"? The network is still called Stack Exchange, even though the company is called something else, and it doesn't really make sense to put Stack Overflow anywhere else than on Stack Overflow, because the use of "Stack Exchange" has been emphasised in a lot of places.

SO and SE have also been [explicitly separated in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271080/332043) when mentioning global changes, as well as [in newer times](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/10/iterating-on-inclusion/) ("[...] Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network")

Comment: That would be consistent with other pages like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).